# How to access List of elements of a Class type?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList that contains the below elements of type class: ListClass

```
public class ListClass {
    String requestPath;             //parse
    List<String> paramsMandatory;   //name, query
    List<String> paramsOptional;    //company
    boolean needBody;               //true
    String mimeType;                //String, json

    public String getRequestPath() {
        return requestPath;
    }
    public void setRequestPath(String requestPath) {
        this.requestPath = requestPath;
    }

    public List<String> getParamsMandatory() {
        return paramsMandatory;
    }
    public void setParamsMandatory(List<String> paramsMandatory) {
        this.paramsMandatory = paramsMandatory;
    }

    public List<String> getParamsOptional() {
        return paramsOptional;
    }
    public void setParamsOptional(List<String> paramsOptional) {
        this.paramsOptional = paramsOptional;
    }

    public boolean isNeedBody() {
        return needBody;
    }
    public void setNeedBody(boolean needBody) {
        this.needBody = needBody;
    }

    public String getMimeType() {
        return mimeType;
    }

    public void setMimeType(String mimeType) {
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }
}
```

Setting the properties of it in another class: PropSetter

```
public class PropSetter {
    List<String> mp = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> op = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void setParameters() {
        mp.add("force");
        mp.add("name");
        op.add("company");
        op.add("location");
        ListClass lc = new ListClass();
        lc.setRequestPath("/parse");
        lc.setParamsMandatory(mp);
        lc.setParamsOptional(op);
        lc.setNeedBody(false);
        lc.setMimeType("String");
        System.out.println("Set the props for ListClass");
    }

}
```

I am trying to return an ArrayList that is of Type: `ListClass` in the below way:

```
List<ListClass> cl = new ArrayList<ListClass>();    
public void setCL() {
    PropSetter ps  = new PropSetter();
    ps.setParameters();
    ListClass lcl  = new ListClass();
    cl.add(lcl);
}
public List<ListClass> getPropList() {
    return cl;
}
```

The method `getPropList` returns the List of type: `ListClass`. How do I access elements in it ?
If it is a particular datatype, I could've used an Iterator or a foreach loop. But this is of a class type: `ListClass` which I dont understand how to access the elements, particularly the lists: paramsMandatory & paramsOptional inside.

I tried to display the elements like:

```
CreateList cl = new CreateList();
cl.setCL();
List<ListClass> ll = cl.getPropList();
System.out.println("Size of Arraylist<ListClass>:" + ll.size());
for (ListClass l: ll) { 
    System.out.println("DS: " + l);
}
```

In my main class, I tried to see if I can print a parameter inside as below.

```
for (ListClass l: ll) { 
    System.out.println("DS: " + l.getRequestPath);
}
```

which gives me a compilation error: `getRequestPath cannot be resolved or is not a field`
I tried to print the size of array and it shows the right value:

```
System.out.println("Size of Arraylist<ListClass>:" + ll.size());
Size of Arraylist<ListClass>: 1
```

Could anyone let me know how can I access the elements coming from : `getPropList`

Comment: `l.getRequestPath()`

Comment: That was a mistake, I tried that and got `DS: null` in the output.

Comment: Your naming standards are so terrible. Are you saving disk space or something so you limit variable name lengths to the minimum? Every IDE has autocomplete so you don't have to type everything manually if that is the problem. In your question you mention `CreateList` - what is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the compiler error you are getting, namely:

> `getRequestPath cannot be resolved or is not a field`

In other words, the compiler thinks that `getRequestPath` is a member of class `ListClass` - because you forgot to add parentheses so as to indicate to the compiler that `getRequestPath` is a method. Hence you need to change that line of your code as follows:

```java
System.out.println("DS: " + l.getRequestPath());
```

Comment: @Metadata I suggest you edit your question and post a [mcve] so that people can understand why `l.getRequestPath()` is returning null.